# Overlay an image (on canvas) on a VideoView?

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to put a canvas over a VideoView. On this canvas I would like to be able to draw Images (or rectangles, lines, ect).

I have the following snippet in my XML file.

```xml
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Again, my goal is to have a canvas over this VideoView so that I can put images on the canvas.

So, I would ultimately have images overlaid on the video. I would also like to be able to overlay rectangles and other elements.

Any help would be extremely appreciated! This was a lot harder than I thought!

Comment: I have made a small amount of success by creating my own custom VideoView class then drawing on its canvas. The problem now is that the original video disappears and only the drawings remain! 

I feel that this is not the best solution anyway. Any help would be really great!!

Comment: Looks like the canvas is locked. How did you manage to draw something anyway?

Comment: canvas.drawPoint then surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost

Comment: I have actually followed this example: http://androidhelpkatariya.blogspot.ca/2012/11/surface-view-example.html



But it seems to kill whatever was on the view before. (VideoView inherits from SurfaceView).

Would somehow overlaying a GLSurfaceView be a good idea? I'm still really confused

Comment: How do companies like Youtube overlay things like Pause and what not?

Comment: I have something kinda working but it's glitchy to say the least

Comment: Glitchy as in, the drawings flash every half second..

Comment: The right way for me would be if you could customize you VideoView and override onDraw(canvas). But now the problem is: probably the MediaPlayer locks the canvas when you call setAnchorView(videoView); So onDraw() is never called and invalide() doesnt work.

Comment: Jeez no one has got a good answer for me!

Comment: My answer doesn't worth the bounty?

Comment: err - ah, I forgot to give it.. Sorry bro. Happy holidays though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written an application that does exactly what you are looking for. Unfortunately I do not have the code with me now but I do remember where I found code that helped me a great deal!

As you can see in this [video](http://youtu.be/48TnVMJGW0A) and this [one](http://youtu.be/xV0rFlOkN_M) it's very much possible to draw whatever you want on top of the video steam, you just need to make sure you don't drop the `FPS` too much.

[Here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/index.html) you can find the tutorial and the code. What I did was I started taking out chunks of the code as after I learned what it did and what I want to change it with. It really speeded up my work on the PoC I worked on.

I hope it helps, and I'll be glad to help you further if you need anything more.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Use a relative layout. Here is what I use to overlay an image in my mapview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >        

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_new_poi_icon_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_new_poi_icon_content_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/overlay_with_watermark"
        android:visibility="gone" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just change the scaletype to what you need and use these params to put it where you want:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
```

Comment: Hi Lentz! Thank you so much for the response. I also wanted to draw other things on this overlay such as rectangles and lines. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You will probably want to use a Canvas or SurfaceView for that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: Yeah.. I've been on this massive hunt but I can't find a solid example of overlaying Canvas in action.

Comment: You cannot use SurfaceView with the VideoView as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

i beleive you need more than an image, right?

so, try this:

1. use GLSurfaceView
2. create an texture
3. create an SurfaceTexture
4. create an Surface with SurfaceTexture
5. tell MediaPlay output to Surface created above
6. render the SurfaceTexture
7. render other widgets(button progressbar etc)